# How to bring Virtual Keyboard manually in android?While we clicking the edit text box,the keyboard want to display?

Tags: android

While we clicking the edit text box,the keyboard want to display?
wat to do any suggestions

in customized view

Answer (score 3):

use this to force Android to **show** soft keyboard:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

and in case you want to **hide**:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(your_edit_text.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        manager.showSoftInput(ed1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

Answer (score 2):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
// only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
manager.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: while clicking the edit text itself the keyboard want to display?

Comment: it will come up as soon as it's clicked or have focus, the soft keyboard is bound to edittext, as you can see in the last line.

Comment: the cursor is blinking in edit text but virtual keyboard doesnt showing .

Comment: i want to display the virtual keyboard which i want to design in customized view

Comment: I'm not getting you. Could edit your question and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How can i show the keyboard along with edittext,but the keyboard wont be default one which is inbuilt in device

Comment: If you have created your own Keyboard (IME) then You'll have to enable it from setting.

Comment: If it's something like a pop-up window, align it with the base of activity, hide the default keyboard and use yours

Comment: will u send me exact the coding

Comment: No. this site is about giving clues, not publishing tuitorials